# Use ValidateSet Command in param block to define parameter

Tags: powershell

I need to write a function which defines a `bool` Parameter automatically with `[ValidateScript()]`.

```
function Deploy-App {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0)]
        [ValidateScript({if (Test-Path .\DeployFiles.txt) { $UseFilepathFile = $true }})]
        [Alias("u")]
        [bool]$UseFilepathFile
    )

    Get-Location
    Write-Host $UseFilepathFile
}
```

Why does this always return `$false` even though the file exists in the current location? Is the usage of `ValidateScript()` wrong and I can't use it like this? How else would I tackle my problem?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. `ValidateScript()` is for validating values passed into a function, not for assigning values to variables. The latter would go into the function bod, e.g. `$UseFilepathFile = Test-Path .\DeployFiles.txt`. Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve. What do you need this for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `ValidateScript` the wrong way, `ValidateScript` is used to validate the input, not set it. Also, you must return $true from the `ValidateScript`, else the script won't work.

What you need is to check if that file exists inside the body of the script itself.

```
if (Test-Path .\DeployFiles.txt) { $UseFilepathFile = $true }
```